# Speed up generation of USE(universal sentence encoder) embeddings

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, transformer-model

I am working on a semantic similarity problem using [universal sentence encoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder). The dataset contains abstracts of scholarly articles. The mean length is around 1500. There are ~300k records in data and it will take quite long to generate USE embedding for all of them. I am looking for ways to optimize this. Currently, generating embedding for 10k rows of data took ~15 mins.

```
from tqdm import tqdm    
use_module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"

model = hub.load(use_module_url)
print ("module %s loaded" % use_module_url)

def embed(input):
  return model(input)

def get_features(texts):
        if type(texts) is str:
            texts = [texts]
        return embed(texts)    

def data_iterator(data):
  chunk_list = []
  for x in tqdm(range(0, len(data), 1000)):
    if x+1000 > len(data):
      chunk_list.append(data[x:len(data)])
    else:
      chunk_list.append(data[x:x+1000])
  return chunk_list

data = df['text'][:10000].values
data_processed = list(map(process_text, data))
```

Here, I want to speed up the generation of USE embeddings for my data. I am experimenting in kaggle kernel and have turned on the GPU. The GPU utilization doesn`t go beyond 2-3% & CPU utilization was ~120%

```
%%time
BASE_VECTORS = []

chunk_list = data_iterator(data_processed)

for i in tqdm(chunk_list):
    BASE_VECTORS_tmp = get_features(i)
    BASE_VECTORS.extend(BASE_VECTORS_tmp)

BASE_VECTORS = np.asarray(BASE_VECTORS)
```

Time taken
CPU times: user 16min 48s, sys: 2min 59s, total: 19min 47s
Wall time: 15min 13s

Answer (score 0):

Probably you had not installed GPU version of tensorflow, or had some CUDNN version mismatch. Normally USE uses GPU a lot.